# how to choose eigenvectors for repeated eigenvalue when we do spectrum decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that different eigenvectors from different eigenspace are automatically orthogonal.

My question is:

Suppose we are doing spectrum decomposition to a 3x3 symmetric matrix and 
we have only two different eigenvalues(which means we have one repeated eigenvalue). Then we can choose two eigenvectors for that repeated eigenvalue and then do Grand-Schmit orthogonalization to these two vectors. But G-S orthogonalization requires linear independent vector here.

Does it mean:

1.We should always pick well selected linearly independent eigenvectors?

2.if 1 holds, can we always guarantee that we can find linearly independent eigenvectors for repeated eigenvalue?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are you dealing with a symmetric matrix?

Comment: @  Minus One-Twelfth Yes and I have edited my answer

Comment: @Tian any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. The eigenspace related to the repeated eigenvalue (double in your case) is 2-dimensional. Hence it has an orthogonal basis consisting of 2 vectors. Any vector from this eigenspace is orthogonal to any eigenvector related to the other eigenvalue.

Comment: (2) holds. Choose any eigenvector, the second 
chosen evec shouldd be orthogonal to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you computed the null space of $A-\lambda I$ for the repeated eigenvalue, you should’ve ended up with a basis for that space. Apply Gram-Schmidt process to these two vectors.

Alternatively, since you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$ you have a short-cut available to you. As user376343 noted, the two eigenspaces are orthogonal complements. Once you have an eigenvector $\mathbf v$ for the simple eigenvalue, then, choose *any* vector orthogonal to it. You can generate one via a simple manipulation of that vector’s components. This orthogonal vector is guaranteed to be an eigenvector of the repeated eigenvalue, and its cross product with $\mathbf v$ is another.